# How to export empty tables in ORACLE 11G?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

Im using oracle 11g to export a database, but they seem to ignore empty tables
Is there any command that i can export all tables?

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter `CONTENT=ALL`. This is the default, but it sounds as if you have `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY` set.

[expdp documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#BABFJADJ)

Comment: When i use the parameter content all , it says 'ALL' is not allowable value for 'content'